# python path directing to older version in PATH

Tags: python, linux

In Linux when I issue the following command:

```
echo $PATH

/opt/python/3.10.8/bin/python3:/home/d5291029/.local/bin:/home/d5291029/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin
```

I get this. My `.bash_profile` is this:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

PATH=/opt/python/3.10.8/bin/python3:$PATH
```

When I source the changes in bash_profile `source .bashprofile` and hit:

```
python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jun 14 2022, 12:54:58)
```

So even though my python is version `3.10` , my path still defaults to the system installation version of python which is `3.6.8`. Why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PATH` should contain directory paths, not program.

You can fix this:

```
PATH=/opt/python/3.10.8/bin:$PATH
```

Don't forget to logout or `exec bash` to reload your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: did it `PATH=/opt/python/3.10.8/bin/:$PATH` in my bash_profile, also `exec bash` afterwards and nothing still 3.6

Comment: What is the output of `ls /opt/python/3.10.8/bin/`. Do you see `python3`?

Comment: ls: cannot access '/opt/python/3.10.8/bin/': Permission denied

Comment: OK. you have your answer :-) If your current user can't access to /opt/python/3.10.8/bin/, the shell cannot find the python3 binary in this directory.

Comment: When you have solved the permission problem, don't forget to fix the `PATH` because `/opt/python/3.10.8/bin/python3` can't work as is.

Comment: why `usr/bin`python3.9` is available when owned by root as well while /opt/bin/python is not when owned by root ? thanks